# Selecting tags based on 2 consecutive tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to select tag h1 having the next element as p using find_all() method but I'm getting empty list. Here is my code,

```
def has_h1_followedby_p(tag):
    return tag.name == 'h1' and tag.next_siblings.name == 'p'

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(filepath), 'html.parser')
h1_tags = soup.find_all(has_h1_followedby_p)
```

I want to know what exactly is wrong with the condition as it seems simple enough. I will be very grateful for any kind of suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`next_siblings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) is a generator that would match all the next siblings, while you need a single one:

```
tag.name == 'h1' and tag.next_sibling and tag.next_sibling.name == "p"
```

Note that we additionally apply the `tag.next_sibling` truthiness check - there can be a situation when `h1` does not have a next sibling.

Or you can search for `p` next sibling (this is not the same as previous version though):

```
tag.name == 'h1' and tag.find_next_sibling("p")
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe for such a proactive response, it worked like a charm.